# I have table in that there is name and its price, in view i have just fetching name from database in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have table in that there is name and its price, in view i have just fetching name from database in dropdownlist. I just want its price in another textbox from database after selecting option from Dropdownlist

the below is database table
[from that table i have only fetching name in dropdown from database after selecting option from dropdown it shows its price in another textbox which is shown in below image][1]
[database table]
**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh7jA.png**

[here is a view][2]
**[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3r5q.png**

here is a view code:-
 
        2D Diagnostic

```
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Investigation_name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DBMySkills"], "-Select-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , @style= "width:50%"})
        </td>
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Investigation_Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Investigation_Price)
    </div>

</div>#
```

Comment: Handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and make an ajax call to a server method (passing the value of the dropdownlist) and have it return the value of the associated price so you can update the textbox

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you Post a code.

Comment: No. SO is not a code writing service. You need to do some research, and if your having problems implementing your code, then ask a question showing what you have tried and explaining what is not working.

Comment: ok thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: What you have tried so far?